# All positive integers $n$ are equal

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

Is my proof correct? I have to prove that:

All positive integers $n$ are equal

$P (n)$: All numbers in a set of $n$ positive integers are equal

Base: $P (1)$ is true

Inductive hypothesis: Suppose that $P(n)$ is true

Induction step: Let $A$ be the set of the first $n + 1$ positive integers.

Let $A'$ the set of the first $n$ positive integers in $A$ (the smallest $n$ integers in $A$).

Let $A''$ be the set of the last $n$ positive integers in $A$ (the largest $n$ integers in $A$).

Then from the fact that $P (n)$ is true we know that:

- all integers in $A'$ are equal
- all the integers in $A''$ are the same

Thus the first $n$ elements of $A$ are equal and the last $n$ elements of $A$ are equal.

So all the elements of $A$ are the same.

So all positive integers are equal.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color

Comment: Do $P(2)$ in details. Why would the elements of $A$ and $A'$ be the same in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flawed proof that all positive integers are equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367033/flawed-proof-that-all-positive-integers-are-equal)

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris So it basically can't be proved because it's a paradox?

Comment: @user560980 Yeah, it cannot be proven because it isn’t true (assuming consistency of ZF, yadda, yadda). In the proof you’re making an implicit assumption, as others have pointed out, about the $P(2)$ case which you should carefully take a look at.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris I don't particularly care whether ZF is consistent when deciding that $1$ and $2$ are not equal. Even if $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't exist, one apple is a different quantity of apples than two apples. Even if mathematics is inconsistent under all possible choices of foundation, that much I think we are all utterly convinced of.

Comment: A classical fake-proof (usually the proof wants to show that all horses have the same color, all girls have the same hair color, or similar statements). The base case is (mathemtically) true, but rather artifical. The step from $1$ to $2$ is obviously wrong. If it were true, the proof actually would work.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Totally correct, we do not need ZFC for statements like $1\ne 2$